# Link to js file in HTML needs to call to a function

Tags: javascript, html

New to HTML and Javascript. Hoping for some guidance. I have saved my javascript as an external link file to clean up my code. However in div class = inner the HTML is calling to a function within the studentformcal.js file... is it possible for me to call a function within an external .js file? If so, what do I need to add to my div class to get this working?

```
<script src="studentformcal.js"></script>

<div class="inner">

    <p>Enter Your Degree Program

    <select name="meal" id="meal" onChange="changecat(this.value);">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="Undergraduate">Undergraduate</option>
        <option value="Graduate">Graduate</option>
    </select></p>

    <p>Choose Course Program    
    <select name="category" id="category" onChange="changePos(this.value);">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    </select></p>

    <p><u>Enter letter grade for the below classes:</u></p>
    <form id="position"></form>

    <div id="total"></div>
    <div id="eligibility"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: If your 2 functions are in studentformcal.js then it should work as is, if its not what happens & what errors are printed in the browsers console.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any function that is loaded in your document. This said, you can load external files in your page:

```
<script src="http://external-server.com/my-file.js"></script>
```

If the file is not loaded in your document you cannot invoke the functions.

EDIT: If by external you mean your studentformcal.js then the answer is yes, you can invoke any function that is exposed in that file.

Comment: Yes, I should have inspected the page. When I did, I see it is not linking the .js file as it should.

Comment: Might be a path related issue?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the HTML file includes your javascript file, then you're able to invoke any function you wrote in your JS file.

As previous users noted, the problem might be in the way you are including the javascript file.

Per your example, make sure `studentformcal.js` is located in the same folder as the current page.

Answer (score 0):

> If your JS file and html file is not in same folder then

```
 <script src="/folder_name/your_js_file.js"></script>
```

> If your JS file and html file are in same folder

```
<script src="your_js_file.js"></script>
```

> Link from external Server

```
 <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/js/myScript1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Aman, they are in the same folder. I am trying to work through the error now that I see when I inspect the folder.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I have < script> < /script > in my .js file. Sorry for the inconvience.